# get_permalink returning site home url instead of the url of slug being passed

Tags: permalinks, slug, pages

I am fetching some testimonials data from db and based on the slugs, I am getting the links to use further. Here is my code

```
function createPageForTestimonials($slug, $title, $content, $companyName){
    $new_page = array(
        'slug' => $slug,
        'title' => $title,
        'content' => $content
    );

    //check if page exists
    if (the_slug_exists($slug)) {
        $url = get_permalink( get_page_by_path( $slug ) );
        return get_permalink( get_page_by_path( $slug ) );
    }
    else {
        $new_page_id = wp_insert_post(array(
            'post_title' => $new_page['title'],
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post_name' => $new_page['slug'],
            'comment_status' => 'closed',
            'ping_status' => 'closed',
            'post_content' => $new_page['content'],
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author' => 1,
            'menu_order' => 0
        ));

        return get_permalink($new_page_id);
    }
}

//check if page exists by its slug
function the_slug_exists($post_name) {
    global $wpdb;
    $post_name = sanitize_title($post_name);
    if($wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = '" . $post_name . "'", 'ARRAY_A'))) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

the function is returning home URL when I move the code to server here, but working fine and returning expected urls on localhost. Here is the [live website](https://5280.us/). I have also debug the issue by checking that `if (the_slug_exists($slug))` returns true every time but the url returned is of homepage, which should not happen. Please let me know how I can debug this issue better or if I am doing something wrong here.